# Qt5 - glTexStorage2D/glBindImageTexture undefined?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, textures

I am using Qt 5.7.0 with OpenGL 4.4 and I'm trying to port over some old code to work with Qt. As far as I understand, Qt doesn't have its own way to handle shader textures so I'm using the following code that works fine in my GLEW, non-Qt project:

```
    float* data = new float[IMAGE_WIDTH * IMAGE_HEIGHT];
    for (int i = 0; i < IMAGE_WIDTH * IMAGE_HEIGHT; ++i)
        data[i] = 0.f;

    GLuint tex[1];
    glGenTextures(1, tex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex[0]);
    glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_R32F, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, data);
    glBindImageTexture(0, tex[0], 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_READ_WRITE, GL_R32F);

    delete[] data;
```

However apparently `glTexStorage2D` and `glBindImageTexture` are undefined. I have looked at the documentation and they should exist. I have tried `#include`ing `QOpenGLFunctions_4_4_Core`, `QOpenGLFunctions_4_2_Core`, `QOpenGLTexture` and `QOpenGLFunctions` but none have solved the problem. I have even looked into the source of `QOpenGLFunctions_4_4_Core`:

```
inline void QOpenGLFunctions_4_4_Core::glTexStorage2D(GLenum target, GLsizei levels, GLenum internalformat, GLsizei width, GLsizei height)
{
    d_4_2_Core->f.TexStorage2D(target, levels, internalformat, width, height);
}
```

Even creating an instance gives me an error:

```
QOpenGLFunctions_4_4_Core gl;
gl.glTexStorage2D((GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_R32F, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT);
```

crashes with "Exception thrown: read access violation. this->d_4_2_Core was nullptr."

Is there a) any way to fix this problem; or better yet b) a Qt way to do image load/store?

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't just use regular OpenGL calls instead of going through Qt's wrappers?

Comment: @NicolBolas I just find the Qt way of doing things much more organised and easier to handle, and I'd rather do everything with Qt rather than half Qt, half regular OpenGL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should acquire a pointer to a `QOpenGLFunctions_4_4_Core` object via [`QOpenGLContext::versionFunctions()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglcontext.html#versionFunctions). ALternativelt, you can create your own object, but then have to to manually load the function pointers using the `initializeOpenGLFunctions()` member function, while the context is made current.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however through trying to get the context I found that the version my base window class was inheriting from was OpenGL 3.1, which is why the functions were undefined; changing that to 4.4 resolved the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Inheriting a specific version of the functions worked for me.

```
class MyWidget: public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions_4_4_Core
{
...
}
```